# Sorting and Mongoose.js findOneAndRemove

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

According to the Mongoose.js docs, it should be possible to add a sort directive to methods passed directly to the database like `findOneAndUpdate` or `findOneAndRemove`.

I'm trying to grab a single document that matches a criterion and remove it from the database. So far, I have tried:

```
Model.findOneAndRemove({foo: 'bar'})
    .sort({created_at: 'asc'})
    .exec(callback);
```

and

```
Model.findOneAndRemove({foo: 'bar'}, {sort: {created_at: 'asc'}}).exec(callback);
```

Both of which seem to ignore the sort instruction and simply find and remove the most recently added matching document, not the document with the earliest `created_at` date.

Issuing the query as a `findOne` and then removing the document in the callback function works as expected, e.g.,

```
Model.findOne({foo: 'bar'}).sort({created_at: 'asc'})
    .exec(function (err, doc) { 
        doc.remove(); 
    });
```

returns and removes the document with the earliest `created_at` date, so I believe that sorting in `findOneAndRemove` queries (which, unlike regular queries, are handed directly to MongoDB) must use a different syntax.

Using `findOne` instead of `findOneAndRemove` is a viable option, but I would prefer that the operation be atomic if at all possible.

Is it possible to use sort directives with Mongoose.js queries like `findOneAndUpdate` or `findOneAndRemove`, and, if so, what syntax is used?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me, like you said, the mongoose doc says it is possible to do it but I can't make it work. See if you can file a bug or send an email to the mongoose crew.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help to change the condition of the sort to:

```
    {created_at: 1}
```

'or'

```
    {created_at: -1}
```

(for ascending or descending respectively). 
Im currently struggling with the findOneAndRemove wrapper as well. It does not seem to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [API Documentation here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove) this appears to be fixed in v3.8.18 of [mongoose.js](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/).

It very likely was fixed earlier, but that's the version I'm using.